# show that $\int_{0}^{1} (-\ln(t))^n dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^n dt$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

show that $\int_{0}^{1} (-\ln(t))^n dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^n dt$

I tried to make a variable change using the change of variables theorem,

with   $u=-\ln (t)$ such that $t=e^{-u}$ and $dt=-e^{-u} du$ thus, we obtain something similar to the r.h.s of, but in terms of u.
$$\int_{0}^{1} (-\ln(t))^n dt=\int_{e^{-\alpha}=0}^0 (-\ln(e^{-u}))^{n}(-e^{-u} )du\\ =\int_{e^{-\alpha}=0}^0 (\ln(e^u))^n (-e^{-u} )du=\int_{e^{-\alpha}=0}^0 u^n (-e^{-u} )du=-\int_{0}^{e^{-\alpha}=0}u^n (-e^{-u} )du$$
In addition, the upper limit is not indefinite, I suppose that here comes the indefinite integral.

Is this a correct path? If so, what should I try to do afterwards?

Comment: Something is not right here. Aren't you missing a $t^n$ in the second integral? Also $t=e^{-t}$ does not make sense. It should be $t=e^{-u}$. Then $dt =-e^u$ is also incorrect. Please think this over again an edit your question.

Comment: I already edited the question, sorry, I was wrong to transcribe from the notebook

Comment: $dt=-e^{-u}du$. Write down what you get exactly after the change of variables.

Comment: I add it, thanks

Comment: Consider $u=-\ln t$. Think about how $-\ln t$ (and hence $u$) changes as $t$ moves from $0+$ to $1$. Also take the $-$ from $(-e^{-u})$ into the front of the integral.

Comment: I can already see, in addition to that, being ln surjective, we can affirm that the last expression is also valid for t instead of u

Comment: The thing is that the original problem should have been stated with $u$ instead of $t$ on the right-hand side to avoid confusion. Of course $t$ is just a dummy variable, the variable of integration. You can just rename it to whatever you like. So in the end you can just rename $u$ to $t$, but it is not important since it does not change anything.